# C# search-replace into php file

Tags: c#, php, replace, syntax, localization

I'm a beginner in C#. I'm trying to make a small tool for search&replace into php file
I have this input:

```
$of_options[] = array(  "name"      => "General Settings",
                         ,"std"   => "General Settings",
                         ,"test"   => "test",
                );
```

I want this output:

```
$of_options[] = array(  'name'      =>__( 'General Settings','$world'),
                         ,"std"   => "General Settings",
                         ,"test"   => "test",
                );
```

This is my try:

```
private string ReplaceBackgroundDirection(string Source)
{   
    return Source.Replace("\"", "'").Replace("=>","=>__(") + ",'$world'),";
}
```

Comment: Why not just use the find-and-replace tool in Notepad or your IDE?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @dai how can use Notepad Method

Comment: @flindeberg trying auto localization php file for poedite

Comment: Which part are you passing to the C# program? Is it each item of the array with key and value as a string i.e. "a => b"?

Comment: Ie you are trying to modify the php source?

Comment: @barrick The problem in this part and how output it "name"=> "General Settings", to 'name' =>__( 'General Settings','$world'), i want my code work for "name" array only

Comment: @flindeberg yes trying to modify the php source like functions.options.php

Answer (score 0):

Using lookbehinds and lookaheads in regular expressions, you can achieve the replace in three parts:

```
        string orig = "\"$of_options[] = array(  \"name\"      => \"General Settings\", ,\"std\"   => \"General Settings\", ,\"test\"   => \"test\", ); \"";

        string output = Regex.Replace(orig,
                                        @"(?<=array\([\s]*)""name""", 
                                        "'name'");
        output = Regex.Replace(output, 
                                  @"(?<='name'[\s]*\=>)[\s]*""", 
                                  "__( '");
        output = Regex.Replace(output, 
                                  @"(?<='name'[\s]*\=>__\(['\w\s]+)\""+(?=\,)", 
                                  "','$world')");
```

Comment: thank you @barrick your Code help me and trying
Source = Source.Replace("\"name\"=>", "\'name\'=> __(' ,'$world \')");
but output this
<?php

$of_options[] = array(  'name'=> __(' ,'$world ') "General Settings",
now how make "General Settings",'$world ')

Comment: It would do - you're simply replacing any occurrence of `"name" =>` with `'name'=> __(','$world ')` there. Show me the original string, before any changes, and what you want, and I will show you what to do.